# EC2 with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have set up an aws micro instance for my node application. I use `socket.io` as well. I am getting the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1393065240268 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

in the console at the moment when the socket connection should be created. Apart from this the node app works. I suspect that the `GET` should not be towards `localhost` but towards the address of the server.

Note that on the server side node logs that it served `socket.io`:

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

Here is a picture of the Security Group of my server:

[image: Security Group].

Socket.io setup:

```
env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
packageJson = require('../package.json'),
http = require('http'),
express = require('express'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express),
SessionSockets = require('session.socket.io'),
path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings'),
expose = require('express-expose')
//Configure server for io and session.socket.io
tmpApp = express(),
tmpServer = http.createServer(tmpApp),
io = require('socket.io').listen(tmpServer),
appCookieParser = express.cookieParser(settings.cookie.secret),
appRedisStore = new RedisStore(),
sessionIO = new SessionSockets(io, appRedisStore, appCookieParser)

global.App = {
    app: tmpApp,
    server: tmpServer,
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    sessionIO: sessionIO,
    io: io,
    start: function() {
        var setUp = this.util('setUp'),
            socketHandler = require('./socketHandler'),
            self = this

            setUp.initialize(function(err, waitingGames) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error at initializing the application')
                    process.exit(0)
                }
                if (!self.started) {
                    self.started = true
                    self.server.listen(self.port)

                    socketHandler()

                    console.log("Running App Version " + App.version + " on port " + App.port + " in " + App.env + " mode")
                }
            })

    },
 ...
 }
```

**UPDATE**

When I changed my port to `80` I get a different error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1393067003774. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ec2-54-214-136-70.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the problem. It was on the client side. I was connecting to `localhost`. It's a stupid error, but during development you don't pay attention to these details and it seemed natural that `socket.io` should connect to the root from where you serve your content.

Since I'm using EC2 and after each restart I get different DNS address I've sent to the page where I'm initializing the `socket.io` the correct the `req.headers.host` (using `express-expose`).

Comment: thank you, thank you :)) I was also using localhost and when i changed it to my url, it worked.

Comment: It should be simpler to set the socket.io server address as '/socket.io' which should reference the server I'm getting the website from. Not sure if socket.io handles that, but it definitely should.